# Automated Growth rate function for heatmap

Tags: r, linear-regression, heatmap

I am making an heatmap using the linear regression slop.

I want to make the same kind of function but instead of the linear regression slop I want to use the growth rate like : (Present value - Past value)/ Past Value * 100.

Here is my code which work for the heatmap with regression slop :

```
data.tablee$Formulation <-
  paste(data.tablee$`Formualmation Description`, data.tablee$Container, sep = "-")
data.tablee <- select(data.tablee,-c("Formualmation Description","Container"))   
# 
colnames(data.tablee)[colnames(data.tablee)=="TimePoint (weeks)"] <- "TimePoint"
colnames(data.tablee)[colnames(data.tablee)=="Stress"] <- "Temperature"

final_data <- data.frame(Formulation=sort(unique(data.tablee$Formulation)))

data.tablee$Study <- NULL

feature_list <- setdiff(colnames(data.tablee),c("TimePoint","Temperature","Formulation"))

for(feature in feature_list){
  
  feature_data <- data.tablee[,c("TimePoint","Temperature","Formulation",feature)]
  
  feature_data <- reshape2::dcast(feature_data,Formulation+TimePoint~Temperature,value.var=feature)
  feature_data=na.omit(feature_data)
  
  for(i in 3:ncol(feature_data)){
    colnames(feature_data)[i] <- paste0(feature," (",colnames(feature_data)[i],")")
    
    final_data[,colnames(feature_data)[i]] <- sapply(final_data$Formulation,FUN=function(x){
      coef(lm(as.formula(paste0("`",colnames(feature_data)[i],"`~TimePoint")),
              subset(feature_data,(Formulation==x)),na.action=na.omit))[["TimePoint"]]
    })
  }
}
rownames(final_data) <- final_data$Formulation
final_data <- abs(final_data[,-1])
heatmap(as.matrix(t(final_data)),cexCol=1,cexRow=1,Rowv=NA,scale="row")
```

The code to reproduct part of my data from dput()

```
structure(list(`SE_HMWS (%)` = c(0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 
                                    0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
                                    0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
                                    0.9, NA, 0.8, 1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 
                                    1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 3.2, 3, 3.1, 3.4, 3, 3.7, 3.1, 2.9, 
                                    3, 3.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 1.6, 1.4, 
                                    1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1.9, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 5.5, 4.9, 5.1, 6, 4.9, 
                                    6, 5.3, 5.1, 5.1, 5.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), `SE_Monomer (%)` = c(96.9, 97, 97, 96.8, 96.9, 96.8, 96.9, 
                        96.9, 96.9, 96.9, 96.9, 97, 97, 96.8, 96.9, 96.8, 96.9, 96.9, 
                        96.9, 96.9, 96.9, 97, 97, 96.8, 96.9, 96.8, 96.9, 96.9, 96.9, 
                        96.9, 96.8, 96.9, 96.8, NA, 96.8, 96.7, 96.8, 96.8, 96.8, 96.8, 
                        95.9, 96.1, 96, 95.9, 96.1, 95.7, 96, 96, 95.9, 96.1, 91.7, 92.1, 
                        92, 91.7, 92.1, 91.2, 92, 92.1, 92.2, 91.9, 96.7, 96.8, 96.8, 
                        96.6, 96.7, 96.6, 96.7, 96.7, 96.7, 96.8, 95.1, 95.3, 95.2, 95, 
                        95.3, 94.7, 95.2, 95.2, 95.2, 95.2, 86.3, 86.9, 86.8, 85.9, 87.1, 
                        85.9, 86.6, 86.7, 87.2, 86.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA), `SE_LMWS (%)` = c(2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 
                                                   2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 
                                                   2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 
                                                   NA, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.8, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 
                                                   2.8, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 5, 5, 5, 4.9, 5, 5.1, 4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 5, 2.4, 
                                                   2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.2, 3.3, 
                                                   3.3, 3.4, 3.3, 3.3, 3.2, 3.3, 8.3, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8, 8.1, 8.1, 
                                                   8.2, 7.7, 8.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Study = c("STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", "STD786", 
                                                                                                                     "STD786"), Stress = c("2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "25±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "25±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", "40±2°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "40±2°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", 
                                                                                                                                           "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C", "2-8°C"), Container = c("Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", 
"Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial", "Glass vial"), `Formualmation Description` = c("STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F1_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F2_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 165mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F3_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F4_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 45mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F5_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F6_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 70mM Arg.HCl, 70mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F7_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 150mM Arg.HCl, 200mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F8_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 225mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F9_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 55mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50", 
"STD786_F10_225mg/mL - 50mM His/His.HCl, 110mM Arg.HCl, 135mM Pro, 0.02% PS80 - pH5.50"
), `TimePoint (weeks)` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = 127:226, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi. Instead of re-posting your question each hour ... it may help to clarify what kind of growth rate you have in mind, i.e. as you have multiple time points you will end up with multiple growth rates per pair of formulation and feature. To me it's not clear how would display them in a heatmap.

Comment: Hello and thank you @stefan , for the growth rate I want only one per formulation_stress calculated with the value at the first time point and the last time point (not the value at the intermediate timepoint)

Comment: Thx Yann. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @stefan , It is exactly what I wanted thank you so much, I have one more question if I wanted to weighted each feature with a coefficient how could I do so (the coef will come from an r handsontable in shiny where we can enter it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach to compute your growth rates which basically means to first reshape your data to long or tidy format. Afterwards we have to do some data wrangling and keep only the first and last time point:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_tidy <- data.tablee |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Formulation, TimePoint, Temperature), names_to = "feature") |>
  mutate(feature = paste0(feature, " (", Temperature, ")")) 

data_growth <- data_tidy |>
  arrange(Formulation, feature, TimePoint) |> 
  group_by(Formulation, feature) |>
  drop_na(value) |> 
  slice(c(1, n())) |> # Keep only first and last time point with non-missing data
  mutate(growth_rate = value / lag(value) - 1) |> 
  drop_na(growth_rate)

data_heat <- data_growth |> 
  select(Formulation, feature, growth_rate) |>
  arrange(Formulation, feature) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = feature, values_from = growth_rate) |>
  as.data.frame()

rownames(data_heat) <- data_heat[[1]]
data_heat[[1]] <- NULL

heatmap(as.matrix(t(data_heat)), cexCol = 1, cexRow = 1, Rowv = NA, scale = "row")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Yann. Not sure how you want to apply this weighting. But as you said the weighting coefficient comes from a dataframe (or a rhandsontable) the general approach which comes to my mind would be use a join, i.e. let's say you have a dataframe with two columns, feature and weighting coefficient, then you could add the weighting coefficient to your data via a left_join by feature. Depending on how and when the weighting should be applied you could perform this step on data_tidy or on data_growth.

Comment: You have been very helpful. I have been trying to do the same thing but with a little change in the formula but I can not succeed in doing it, I want to do : (Present value - Past value)/(present timepoint - past timepoint) * 100

Comment: Try with `growth_rate = (value - lag(value)) / (timepoint - lag(timepoint)) * 100`